# Solr cloud cannot find plugin - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solrconfig

I'm running a solr cloud cluster and using a custom search component - [request-sanitizer-component](https://github.com/cominvent/request-sanitizer-component).

config:

```
Server count: 8
Shards: 16
Replication factor: 3
Max shards per node: 6
```

I've defined the search component in solrconfig.xml:

```
<searchComponent runtimeLib="true" name="request-sanitizer" version="1" class="com.cominvent.solr.RequestSanitizerComponent"/>
```

I have uploaded the plugin jar to the .system collection, following the steps in the [solr guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/adding-custom-plugins-in-solrcloud-mode.html).

I then add the plugin jar to my collection using the [config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/config-api.html) with this curl:

```
curl http://solr-220.soma.plos.org:8983/solr/50_2/config -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
    "add-runtimelib": { "name":"request-sanitizer", "version":1 }
}'
```

Then I add the search component:

```
curl http://solr-220.soma.plos.org:8983/solr/50_2/config -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
  "add-searchcomponent": {
    "name": "request-sanitizer",
    "runtimeLib": true,
    "class": "com.cominvent.solr.RequestSanitizerComponent",
    "sanitize": "rows=>50:50" }
}'
```

The plugin jar and search component are added to `configoverlay.json` at `http://solr-220.soma.plos.org:8983/solr/50_2/config/overlay`:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "overlay":{
    "znodeVersion":4,
    "runtimeLib":{"request-sanitizer":{
        "name":"request-sanitizer",
        "version":1}},
    "searchComponent":{"request-sanitizer":{
        "name":"request-sanitizer",
        "runtimeLib":true,
        "class":"com.cominvent.solr.RequestSanitizerComponent",
        "sanitize":"rows=>50:50"}}}}
```

However, when I try to query the collection, I get the following exception:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/handler/component/SearchComponent`

What is wrong with my configuration?

**Notes**

For the 1st attempt I placed the jar in SOLR_HOME/lib.
This worked initially for clusters with a small number of shards - collection creation would throw the same NoClassDefFoundError exceptions, but they would disappear after a server restart.

However, when I increased to 8 shards, the creation threw the same exceptions *and* the collection was never created. This is why I decided to use the config API, but I would also accept a solution that uses SOLR_HOME/lib. One possibility is to force the collection to remain, even with numerous startup errors, if that is possible.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

We had two instances of the request-sanitizer jar in the classpath. Removing one of the jars solved the problem.